# Magento Admin Customer Edit Password not Work

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

The following error occure during password edit

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getBackend() on
>   boolean in
>   /var/www/vhosts/stormboy.com.au/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php:1553
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/vhosts/stormboy.com.au/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php(240):
>   Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->saveAttribute(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer),
>   'password_create...') #1
>   /var/www/vhosts/stormboy.com.au/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php(240):
>   Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer->changePassword(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer),
>   '*RWN2Q6q') #2
>   /var/www/vhosts/stormboy.com.au/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php(367):
>   Mage_Customer_Model_Customer->changePassword('*RWN2Q6q') #3
>   /var/www/vhosts/stormboy.com.au/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController->saveAction() #4
>   /var/www/vhosts/stormboy.com.au/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254):
>   in
>   /var/www/vhosts/stormboy.com.au/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php
>   on line 1553

Comment: i have same issue please help me sort out

Comment: So, share your store url and details please.

Comment: shared the same in email

Comment: which email id bro.

Comment: ok I wil update you soon.

Comment: dont write here email bro

Comment: sir any hope  to solve this